# pivot table in userForm in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

Any idea about how to embed/insert pivotTable/pivotChart in a userForm?

*code sample will be great to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try looking at the Microsoft Office PivotTable 11.0 Control available when you right-click in the Control toolbox?

This lets you embed a Pivot Table in a Form.

Comment: What version of Excel were you using that had this?

Comment: 7 years later I don't remember...