# Is it possible to use a Pivot Table in a userform?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Is it possible to insert a pivot table into a userform in VBA? I saw this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174425/pivot-table-in-userform-in-excel-vba) about it, but I'm able to find the `Microsoft Office PivotTable control` in the right-click menu. I did find the Tree View, but that isn't quite the same thing I don't think.

**UPDATE**

I'm creating an Inventory workbook for use in my office. I'll allow others to use it to see what we have and to request items that we have in inventory. I'm going to use the `Userform` for this. I have a dashboard for myself in the workbook that has several pivot tables already. There are 2 that I'd like to use in the `Userform`.

The regular users won't have access to edit the workbook, or even to change which sheet is showing, they only need access to view the 2 pivots that I want to add to this `Userform`.

So, the end result is going to be that the end user will have a pivot table that will allow them to see what we have in inventory and request it or send an email that will create a PO to order it.

Comment: That question is really old. What version of Office you are using? In office 2016 this control is not available anymore.

Comment: I am using Office 2016

Comment: Interesting question. Could you elaborate further about why you'd like this in a UserForm and not just on the grid, as I'm curious about what this would add.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Excel for a very long time and I've never heard of anyone need this combination (UserForm+PT), but anyway, I did a quick Google search and came up with this.

```
Option Explicit

Dim cnnConnection As Object

Private Sub Form_Load()

   Dim strProvider As String
   Dim view As PivotView
   Dim fsets As PivotFieldSets
   Dim c As Object
   Dim newtotal As PivotTotal

   strProvider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
   ' Create an ADO object
   Set cnnConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   ' Set the provider and open the connection to the database
   cnnConnection.Provider = strProvider
   cnnConnection.Open "C:\pivottest.mdb"
   ' Set the pivot table's connection string to the cnnConnection's connection string
   PivotTable1.ConnectionString = cnnConnection.ConnectionString
   ' SQL statement to get everything from table1
   PivotTable1.CommandText = "Select * from table1"

   ' Get variables from the pivot table
   Set view = PivotTable1.ActiveView
   Set fsets = PivotTable1.ActiveView.FieldSets
   Set c = PivotTable1.Constants

   ' Add Category to the Row axis and Item to the Column axis
   view.RowAxis.InsertFieldSet fsets("Category")
   view.ColumnAxis.InsertFieldSet fsets("Item")

   ' Add a new total - Sum of Price
   Set newtotal = view.AddTotal("Sum of Price", view.FieldSets("Price").Fields(0), c.plFunctionSum)
   view.DataAxis.InsertTotal newtotal
   view.DataAxis.InsertFieldSet view.FieldSets("Price")

   ' Set some visual properties
   PivotTable1.DisplayExpandIndicator = False
   PivotTable1.DisplayFieldList = False
   PivotTable1.AllowDetails = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Terminate()
  ' Remove reference to the ADO object
  Set cnnConnection = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub PivotTable1_DblClick()
   Dim sel As Object
   Dim pivotagg As PivotAggregate
   Dim sTotal As String
   Dim sColName As String
   Dim sRowName As String

   Dim sMsg As String

   ' Get the selection object you double-clicked on
   Set sel = PivotTable1.Selection
   ' If it is a aggregate, you can find information about it
   If TypeName(sel) = "PivotAggregates" Then
      ' Select the first item

      Set pivotagg = sel.Item(0)
      ' Display the value
      MsgBox "The cell you double-clicked has a value of '" & pivotagg.Value & "'.", vbInformation, "Value of Cell"

      ' Get variables from the cell
      sTotal = pivotagg.Total.Caption
      sColName = pivotagg.Cell.ColumnMember.Caption
      sRowName = pivotagg.Cell.RowMember.Caption

      ' Display the row and column name
      sMsg = "The value is " & sTotal & " by " & sRowName & " by " & sColName
      MsgBox sMsg, vbInformation, "Value Info"
   End If
End Sub
```

See if you can adapt that concept to your specific setup.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/235542/how-to-use-the-pivottable-office-web-component-with-vb